# Clear formData after $.ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'file', input.files[0] );
fd.name = 'something';
fd.etc = 'something more';

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/script.php',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

I put above code within a submit event, I found in my backend I received duplicated formData's data. Because after submit I did not want to hard refresh the page for good UX. How to clear the formData after ajax's success?

Comment: Everytime you do `new FormData()` you create a new one ?

Comment: @adneo yes I declare var fd = new FormData() within my submit event.

Comment: Are you asking how to clear the `FormData` variable or how to clear the form that appears on the screen?

Comment: @Barmar clearing the variable of formdata doesn't clear the `content` appended to the formdata

Comment: If you clear the variable and create a new `FormData` for each request, it won't have duplicate content.